# How to make a program that prints only the numbers that are divisible by 3, using for and while?

Tags: for-loop, while-loop

How to make a program that prints only the numbers that are divisible by number 3, between the range given by the user, using for and while? User gives the minimum and the maximum numbers in textboxes.

Example: User gives minimum number 1, maximum number 45 and the numbers which program only prints are 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 33, 36, 39, 42, 45.

Comment: Have you made any attempt yourself? Which programming language is your professor asking you to use?

Comment: I have tried myself already but I can't make it work properly.. And I'm using c#

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ever program you should at least try a little yourself. 
You are talking about Textboxes so it is probably not a console application or is it just a figure of speech. Which programming language do you use (C/C++, Java, ...) and what IDE (Visual Studio / QT Creator) ?
You can start with Taras's answer but be careful, one input is missing.

Comment: I have tried myself already but I can't make it work properly.. And I'm using c#.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C++, your loops should be:

For loop:

```
int number;
cout<<"Please enter a number between 1 and 45\n";
cin >> number;
for(int i=0;i<=number;i++)
{
   if((i%3) == 0) // i % 3 - reminder from devision on 3
      cout<<i<<" ";
}
```

While loop:

```
int number;
cout<<"Please enter a number between 1 and 45\n";
cin >> number;
int i=0;
while(i<=number)
{
      cout<<i<<" ";
      i = i +3;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Taras, now my code works properly with for, just added the if-part to my code! Do you have any clue how it works with while? My while-code does not work properly either.

Comment: Why would you do it like this? There is a very simple way to completely remove the need for an if and modulus operation at all.

Comment: Never mind, I made it myself and it works now. Thanks anyway.

Comment: If you are satisfied with my answer - you can accept it =)